# Black Screen after Ubuntu Logo

Tags: 12.04, login, screen

I deleted all partitions and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Well, when I startup my PC, after the Ubuntu's logo, a black screen appears but I hear the log on sound.

If I restart and connect other screen, the OS starts sucessfully. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

I have had this problem too.

In my case, it was an issue with the brightness level of the screen.
What i had to do, was to turn up the brightness, using the "fn" keys.
For the record my laptop is a HP Pavilion g6, and the issue was fixed in a later update.
This might just be your issue. :)

PS: Please remember to rate, if this helped you. :)